# Replace values in array of nested document with documents from other collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

The collection Shops contains nested documents. Using the aggregation framework, I want to get all documents from Shops with the UIDs in the field "products" being replaced with the actual product document from the collection Products.

I have two collections like this:

```
// collection Shops
[
  {
    "name": "Shop A",
    "countries": [
      {
        "name": "Germany",
        "cities": [
          {
            "name": "Berlin",
            "districts": [
              {
                "name": "First District",
                "products": [1, 2, 3]
              },
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]

//  collection Products
[
  {
    "uid": 1,
    "name": "Banana",
  },
  {
    "uid": 2,
    "name": "Apple",
  },
  {
    "uid": 2,
    "name": "Peach",
  }
]
```

**Desired outcome:**

```
[
  {
    "name": "Shop A",
    "countries": [
      {
        "name": "Germany",
        "cities": [
          {
            "name": "Berlin",
            "districts": [
              {
                "name": "First District",
                "products": [
                  {
                    "uid": 1,
                    "name": "Banana",
                  },
                  {
                    "uid": 2,
                    "name": "Apple",
                  },
                  {
                    "uid": 2,
                    "name": "Peach",
                  }
                ]
              },
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I tried `$lookup` as described [here in the mongo docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#use--lookup-with-an-array) but that did not work with this nested document structure.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It can be done with this structure in few stages, but this means that the structure is not right for this. I would consider changing the structure to a document per shop, country, city and district, where only `products` is an array.

Comment: you mean to split the collection Shops into multiple collections: Shops, Countries, Cities, Districts, Products?

Comment: Wouldn't this be against the intention of mongo/ nosql?

Comment: No need to split the collection. You can have one collection of shops. See my answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you really want to do this, one option is:

```
db.Shops.aggregate([
  {$lookup: {
      from: "Products",
      localField: "countries.cities.districts.products",
      foreignField: "uid",
      as: "res"
  }},
  {$project: {
      countriesA: {
        $map: {
          input: "$countries",
          as: "country",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$country",
              {
                cities: {
                  $map: {
                    input: "$$country.cities",
                    as: "city",
                    in: {
                      $mergeObjects: [
                        "$$city",
                        {
                          districts: {
                            $map: {
                              input: "$$city.districts",
                              as: "district",
                              in: {
                                $mergeObjects: [
                                  "$$district",
                                  {
                                    products: {
                                      $map: {
                                        input: "$$district.products",
                                        in: {
                                          $arrayElemAt: [
                                            "$res",
                                            {
                                              $indexOfArray: [
                                                "$res.uid",
                                                "$$this"
                                              ]
                                            }
                                          ]
                                        }
                                      }
                                    }
                                  }
                                ]
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See How it works on the [mongoDB playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/B84aQbyxyjh)

**But:**

I would consider changing the structure to a document per shop, country, city and district, where only products is an array. Like this:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "name": "Shop A",
    "countryName": "Germany",
    "cityName": "Berlin",
    "districtName": "First District",
    "products": [1, 2, 3]
}
```

Which can use the query:

```
db.Shops.aggregate([
  {$lookup: {
      from: "Products",
      localField: "products",
      foreignField: "uid",
      as: "res"
  }},
  {$set: {
      products: {$map: {
          input: "$products",
          in: {$arrayElemAt: ["$res", {$indexOfArray: ["$res.uid", "$$this"]}]}
      }},
      res: "$$REMOVE"
  }}
])
```

Comment: Beautiful, thank you! I like your proposal for a flat document structure, the issues is that i reduced, to focus on the issue, the data structure massively. The actual documents contain on each level (country, city, district, etc) 5-15 more fields. In general when working with mongo db, is it rather recommended to have a flat document structure where each document is possibly hughe (50-70 fields) or have deeper nested structures and less fields per level?

Comment: Regarding maintainability, I am using python with Beanie ORM wich allows easily to manage the nested documents with python classes. So this from my perspective leaves complexity of queries and query speed ?

Comment: If you must use this structure, it is better to do it in the query and not on the code.

Comment: regarding the best practice, it is better to use flat where it is possible. It is OK to use nested object, but it is better to reduce the levels of them. The right structure is according to your usage and needs...