# Lookup/ multiple collections for a single deeply nested document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have three collections in a database:

1. distributors
2. fruits
3. tools

I need to chain/ lookup the collections fruits and tools for a single document from the distributor collection.

The number of documents in fruits and tools is quite limited in practice (max 5-10 each). So performance-wise i guess that should be fine.

The data structure is available at: https://mongoplayground.net/p/AkCarFmdJh1

```
db={
  "distributors": [
    {
      "name": "Distributor 1",
      // more attributes here
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Country 1",
          // more attributes here
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "City 1",
              // more attributes here
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "Shop 1",
                  // more attributes here
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "name": "Fruit 1",
                      // more attributes here
                      "child": "f1"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "fruits": [
    {
      "uid": "f1",
      "name": "Fruit 1 Detail",
      "variants": [
        {
          "uid": "v1",
          "name": "Variant 1",
          "tools": [
            "t1",
            "t2"
          ]
        },
        {
          "uid": "v2",
          "name": "Variant 2",
          "tools": [
            "t3",
            "t4"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
  ],
  "tools": [
    {
      "uid": "t1",
      "name": "Tool 1"
    },
    {
      "uid": "t2",
      "name": "Tool 2"
    },
    {
      "uid": "t3",
      "name": "Tool 3"
    },
    {
      "uid": "t4",
      "name": "Tool 4"
    }
  ]
}
```

- The distributors collection contains deeply nested documents. On the last level, the child “f1” UID should be replaced with the respective document from the collection “fruits”.
- Collection “fruits” contains in the field “tools” UIDs fro the collection “tools”. They also should be replaced with the respective documents from the collection “tools”.
- In the end, I need an aggregation query that results in chaining all three collections into one.

I tried to solve this with $lookup but I am not sure how i can reach/ chain the deeper levels in documents.

**GOAL:**

```
{
"name": "Distributor 1",
"children": [
    {
        "name": "Country 1",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "City 1",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "Shop 1",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "name": "Fruit 1",
                                "child": {
                                    "uid": "f1",
                                    "name": "Fruit 1 Detail",
                                    "variants": [
                                        {
                                            "uid": "v1",
                                            "name": "Variant 1",
                                            "tools": [
                                                { "uid": "t1", "name": "Tool 1" },
                                                { "uid": "t2", "name": "Tool 2" },
                                            ],
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "uid": "v2",
                                            "name": "Variant 2",
                                            "tools": [
                                                { "uid": "t3", "name": "Tool 3" },
                                                { "uid": "t4", "name": "Tool 4" },
                                            ],
                                        },
                                    ],
                                },
                            }
                        ],
                    }
                ],
            }
        ],
    }
],
```

}

Thanks for your help!

(I tried different other approaches to model the distributor collection more flat but i could not find a solution that would be easier to handle in the application, unfortunately. Any suggestion is welcome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To continue our [previous discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78039937/replace-values-in-array-of-nested-document-with-documents-from-other-collection), one option is:

```
db.distributors.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "uid": "d1"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "fruits",
      localField: "children.children.children.children.child",
      foreignField: "uid",
      as: "fruits"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "tools",
      localField: "fruits.variants.tools",
      foreignField: "uid",
      as: "tools"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      tools: "$$REMOVE",
      fruits: {
        $map: {
          input: "$fruits",
          as: "f",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$f",
              {
                variants: {
                  $map: {
                    input: "$$f.variants",
                    as: "v",
                    in: {
                      $mergeObjects: [
                        "$$v",
                        {
                          tools: {
                            $map: {
                              input: "$$v.tools",
                              as: "t",
                              in: {
                                $arrayElemAt: [
                                  "$tools",
                                  {
                                    $indexOfArray: [
                                      "$tools.uid",
                                      "$$t"
                                    ]
                                  }
                                ]
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      countriesA: {
        $map: {
          input: "$children",
          as: "country",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$country",
              {
                children: {
                  $map: {
                    input: "$$country.children",
                    as: "city",
                    in: {
                      $mergeObjects: [
                        "$$city",
                        {
                          children: {
                            $map: {
                              input: "$$city.children",
                              as: "shop",
                              in: {
                                $mergeObjects: [
                                  "$$shop",
                                  {
                                    children: {
                                      $map: {
                                        input: "$$shop.children",
                                        as: "fruit",
                                        in: {
                                          $mergeObjects: [
                                            "$$fruit",
                                            {
                                              child: {
                                                $arrayElemAt: [
                                                  "$fruits",
                                                  {
                                                    $indexOfArray: [
                                                      "$fruits.uid",
                                                      "$$fruit.child"
                                                    ]
                                                  }
                                                ]
                                              }
                                            }
                                          ]
                                        }
                                      }
                                    }
                                  }
                                ]
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See How it works on the [mongoDB playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3ssAw0UZPYO)

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved my day! It's quite hard for me to wrap my head around this construct of $map and $mergeObjects, I probably need to play with this on smaller examples to get the hang of it. Anyway, now I can at least go forwards, thanks again!

Comment: your solution replaces the complete object  `{"name": "Fruit 1","child": "f1"}` with the respective document from the fruits collection. How would you change your solution to just replace the value "f1" from the field child with the respective document from fruits, and not replace the whole object?

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly